# A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [6.0.402] from [/app/global.json] was not found

Tags: c#, docker

So I generated a project with dotnet new webapi and I added a Dockerfile,when I try to run
`docker build -t pregrad/weatherapi .`  I get the following message:

```
[+] Building 1.1s (13/14)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1                                                                                                                                           0.4s 
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1                                                                                                                                              0.4s 
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1@sha256:1830f7a5dbe41cc341235072f9b1c2de7163a4c89b505a4a31a5fbe3b281539e                                                                             0.0s 
 => [build-env 1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1@sha256:53a7a7d70ac0473e9e06ccd8a4992160b58952c3dbdd91ef3e6c28dc5760ed6f                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 1.61kB                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [build-env 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => CACHED [build-env 3/6] COPY *.csproj ./                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => CACHED [build-env 4/6] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [build-env 5/6] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s 
 => ERROR [build-env 6/6] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out                                                                                                                                                      0.4s 
------
 > [build-env 6/6] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out:
#13 0.381 A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [6.0.402] from [/app/global.json] was not found
#13 0.381 Install the [6.0.402] .NET Core SDK or update [/app/global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
#13 0.381   3.1.424 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out]: exit code: 145
```

When I run dotnet --list-sdks I get the following:

```
3.1.424 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about Docker is that it's very self-contained and isolated from the host machine. So it doesn't matter what SDKs are installed on the host machine. There doesn't even need to be a single .NET SDK installed on the host machine. It only matters what SDK you use in your Dockerfile.

The logs show that you're using the 3.1 SDK in the line

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
```

You need to edit your Dockerfile, so it uses the 6.0 SDK by changing the line to (note that there's no longer `core` in the name)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
```

Further down in the Dockerfile you'll see that it uses the 3.1 aspnet image as the runtime image. The line is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
```

You must change that to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
```

so it matches the SDK version.

Comment: Thank you Hans Kilian, I was trying to fumble around with the versions in Dockerfile,but I didn't know about the core part :D, thank you again!